# When I try to write to wav in c++, it says corrupt file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, audio, wav

I am trying to write to wav by taking data from the microphone input, and other headers, and putting that into the wav file. I do that, but it still says corrupted file. One note about the code is that in the struct with the headers, it's not in the correct order. In the WriteToWav function I entered it in the correct order based on the chunk and sub chunks. Here's the code:

````
struct WavHeaders {
      //Fmt
      char SubChunk1ID[4];
      int SubChunk1Size = 16;
      int AudioFormat = 1;
      int NumChannels = 2;
      int SampleRate = 44100;
      int BitsPerSample = 16;
 
      int ByteRate = SampleRate * NumChannels * BitsPerSample / 8;
      int BlockAlign = NumChannels * BitsPerSample / 8;
 
      //Data
      char SubChunk2ID[4];
      int SubChunk2Size = 1 * NumChannels * BitsPerSample / 8;
 
      //RIFF
      char ChunkID[4];
      int ChunkSize = 4 + (8 + SubChunk1Size) + (8 + SubChunk2Size);
      char Format[4];
    };
 
void _AudioReader::AudioReader::AudioToWav() {
    WAVEFORMATEX wfx = {};
    wfx.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;       // PCM is standard
    wfx.nChannels = 2;                      // 2 channels = stereo sound
    wfx.nSamplesPerSec = 44100;             // Samplerate.  44100 Hz
    wfx.wBitsPerSample = 16;                // 16 bit samples
 
    wfx.nBlockAlign = wfx.wBitsPerSample * wfx.nChannels / 8;
    wfx.nAvgBytesPerSec = wfx.nBlockAlign * wfx.nSamplesPerSec;
 
    HWAVEIN wi;
    waveInOpen(
        &wi,         
        WAVE_MAPPER,    
        &wfx,          
        NULL, NULL,     
        CALLBACK_NULL | WAVE_FORMAT_DIRECT  
    );
 
    char buffers[2][44100 * 2 * 2 / 2];   
    WAVEHDR headers[2] = { {},{} };         
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i){
        headers[i].lpData = buffers[i];
        headers[i].dwBufferLength = 44100 * 2 * 2 / 2;      
 
        waveInPrepareHeader(wi, &headers[i], sizeof(headers[i]));
        waveInAddBuffer(wi, &headers[i], sizeof(headers[i]));
    }
 
    //Set Header IDS as char array
    WavHeaders Wav_Headers;
    Wav_Headers.SubChunk1ID[0] = 'f';
    Wav_Headers.SubChunk1ID[1] = 'm';
    Wav_Headers.SubChunk1ID[2] = 't';
    Wav_Headers.SubChunk1ID[3] = ' ';
 
    Wav_Headers.SubChunk2ID[0] = 'd';
    Wav_Headers.SubChunk2ID[1] = 'a';
    Wav_Headers.SubChunk2ID[2] = 't';
    Wav_Headers.SubChunk2ID[3] = 'a';
 
    Wav_Headers.ChunkID[0] = 'R';
    Wav_Headers.ChunkID[1] = 'I';
    Wav_Headers.ChunkID[2] = 'F';
    Wav_Headers.ChunkID[3] = 'F';
 
    Wav_Headers.Format[0] = 'W';
    Wav_Headers.Format[1] = 'A';
    Wav_Headers.Format[2] = 'V';
    Wav_Headers.Format[3] = 'E';
   
    std::ofstream AudioFile("Audio.wav", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary);
 
    //Write Headers to audio file
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) //RIFF Chunk
        AudioFile << Wav_Headers.ChunkID[i];
    AudioFile << Wav_Headers.ChunkSize << Wav_Headers.Format;
 
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) //fmt(format) sub-chunk
        AudioFile << Wav_Headers.SubChunk1ID[i];
    AudioFile << 
        Wav_Headers.SubChunk1Size <<
        Wav_Headers.AudioFormat <<
        Wav_Headers.NumChannels <<
        Wav_Headers.SampleRate <<
        Wav_Headers.ByteRate << 
        Wav_Headers.BlockAlign <<
        Wav_Headers.BitsPerSample;
 
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) //Data sub-chunk
        AudioFile << Wav_Headers.SubChunk2ID[i];
    AudioFile << Wav_Headers.SubChunk2Size;
 
    std::cout << "Started recording! Press escape when you're ready to stop!\n";
    waveInStart(wi);
  
    while (!(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE) & 0x8000)) {
        for (auto& h : headers) {
            if (h.dwFlags & WHDR_DONE) {
               
                AudioFile.write(h.lpData, h.dwBufferLength); //dump audio binary to wav file
 
                h.dwFlags = 0;        
                h.dwBytesRecorded = 0; 
 
                waveInPrepareHeader(wi, &h, sizeof(h));
                waveInAddBuffer(wi, &h, sizeof(h));
            }
        }
    }
    waveInStop(wi);
    for (auto& h : headers){
        waveInUnprepareHeader(wi, &h, sizeof(h));
    }
    waveInClose(wi);
}```
````

Comment: Maybe because it is. Did you check your output vs. a known-good file with exactly the same parameters and samples?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd trust `<<` to do the right thing here. At all. You're going to need to ensure the output is actually the right numerical format *and endian form* for each and every value. Those have precise sizes you *must* match exactly.

Comment: How do I go about doing that @tadman

Comment: Also I can't use .write with an int. It needs to be a const char*.

Comment: Exactly. You need to properly serialize this, not just use `<<` and hope it all works out. You need to write in the proper "packed binary" format. Either find a library, or make a methods like `write_u16(ostream& s, uint16_t value)` which does it properly, one for each type you need.

Comment: what does write_u16 do exactly

Comment: It writes an unsigned 16-bit integer to the file correctly, however that needs to be done in the case of WAV. You might want to dig up some C or C++ code that works with these types of files to see how they do it. Innumerable examples abound as this format has been around since the early 1990s.

Comment: You can write the WAV file follow the MSDN guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ee419050(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: How would I go about making that method, and do I need to use for for every single object in the header?

Comment: Also in the doc it talks about CWaveHeader. I can't seem to use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was that I had to keep in mind formatting and Endianess. Instead of using << or .write, you have to have a precise format for it. A way to write to the file in the correct format is to use the following function I used below, and enter the same WAV headers.

```cpp
template <typename T>
    std::ostream& LittleEndianToFile(std::ostream& file, T value, unsigned size = sizeof(T)) {
        for (; size; --size, value >>= 8)
            file.put(static_cast <char> (value & 0xFF));
        return file;
    }
```

usage: `LittleEndianToFile(AudioFile,SampleRate, 4);`